# Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S4 object with class RasterBrick

Tags: raster, r, mosaic

I have various climate projections for different values such. I extracted the certain values I needed using the brick function. Afterwards I took the average using the mosaic function. I want to use this mosaic to plot maps but R doesn't recognize the new mosaic brick as a data frame or raster. How can I use the output of the mosaic? The error I get is as follows:

> Error: data must be a data frame, or other object coercible by fortify(), not an S4 object with class RasterBrick.

Is there another way to average the raster bricks which I can use for the ggplot2 analysis?

Here you can see the essence of my code

```
# create bricks from net cdf files

Climateproj1 <- brick(fn1)
Climateproj2 <- brick(fn2)
Climateproj3 <- brick(fn3)
Climateproj4 <- brick(fn4)

mosaic <- mosaic (Climateproj1, Climateproj2 , Climateproj3, Climateproj4, fun=mean)

ggplot()+   
  geom_raster(data = mosaic, aes(x=Long, y=Lat, fill = precipitation))
```

Comment: First, do not name objects the same as functions in your environment.  It could be that `geom_raster` is trying to digest the mosaic function rather than your object. I am not sure that this plot function recycles so may not accept multiple rasters via a brick/stack class. Have you tried specifying a raster in the brick (eg., `r[[1]]`)? Also, are you sure that Long/Lat are correct? Usually it is simply x and y. The fill should also match the name in the raster object (using `names(r)`). This may already be the case but, you have not shown us any information about your data.

Comment: Also, every use i have seen of `geom_raster` has converted the raster object to an sp or data.frame class. This is likely the source of the fortify error. Perhaps review your entire approach and use something like levelplot or the rasterVis package for plotting native raster objects.